# TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined when trying to read from firebase

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I've tried to read answers to similar question but couldn't solve my function.

I am building an app for coupons, and I am working now on the function for reacquiring coupons. They way I designed it is so that once a week the function would go through a list of the coupons that should reoccur, and create a similar coupon for the week after.
The previous coupon is then removed from the list.

I've currently set the function for 2 minute intervals to check the function, and I keep getting this error

`Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value`

Followed by this error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined` but I can't understand why.

This is my function:

```
exports.createRecurringDeals = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 2 minutes').timeZone('Asia/Jerusalem').onRun((context) => {
    db.collection('recurring_deals').get().then(querySnapshot => {

        querySnapshot.forEach(bus => {
            const businessListDoc = bus.data();

            if (businessListDoc !== undefined) {

                return db.doc('businesses/' + bus.id).get().then(busDoc => {

                    const business = busDoc.data();

                    if (business !== undefined) {

                        businessListDoc.list.forEach((deal:string) => {
                            return db.doc('deals/' + deal).get().then(snapshot => {
                                const oldDeal = snapshot.data();
                                if (oldDeal !== undefined) {

                                    const promises: any = [];

                                    const startTime = oldDeal.startTime + oldDeal.interval;
                                    const endTime = oldDeal.endTime + oldDeal.interval;

                                    const newDealDoc = db.collection('deals').doc();

                                    const newDeal = {
                                        id: newDealDoc.id,
                                        business_ID: business.id,
                                        business_name: business.name,
                                        business_address_text: business.address_text,
                                        business_address_lat: business.address_lat,
                                        business_address_long: business.address_long,
                                        business_phone_number: business.phone_number,
                                        business_image: business.restaurant_photos[0],
                                        business_categories: business.categories,
                                        business_sub_categories: business.sub_categories,
                                        discount: oldDeal.discount,
                                        timestamp_start: startTime,
                                        timestamp_end: endTime,
                                        gmt: oldDeal.gmt,
                                        amount: oldDeal.amount,
                                        claimers: [],
                                        active: true
                                    };

                                    promises.push(newDealDoc.set(newDeal));

                                    promises.push(db.doc('recurring_deals/' + business.id).update({ list: FieldValue.arrayRemove(oldDeal.id) }));

                                    promises.push(db.doc('recurring_deals/' + business.id).update({ list: FieldValue.arrayUnion(newDeal.id) }));

                                    return Promise.all(promises).catch(err => console.log(err));

                                } else {
                                    return null;
                                };
                            }).catch(err => console.log(err));
                        });
                        return null;
                    } else {
                        return null;
                    };
                }).catch(err => console.log(err));
            } else {
                return null;
            };
        });
        return null;
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
});
```

This is how my data is structured:

Documents of businesses:

[image]

Documents of deals:

[image]

And then these are the documents of lists of recurring deals. Notice, these documents have the same ID as the business they belong to:

[image]

I keep going through the function and all the data seems to be in the right place, with no misspells, so why isn't it working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is most probably in this line:

```
business_image: business.restaurant_photos[0]
```

1. Try checking your spelling
2. Check if your database contains given field
3. Check if that field is array

Comment: Amazing! That was it.